# Predicting willingness-to-pay for a risk-averse person who can 'select' lotteries

Tags: decision-theory, risk, stochastic-ordering

I'm studying how the willingness-to-pay differs for individuals who can 'select' lotteries. Individuals are presented with L1 first and can pay some amount to get lottery L2. Assume these are my lotteries:

**L1**: 100 with probability 0.5 and 20 with probability 0.5

**L2**: 120 with probability 0.5 and 20 with probability 0.5

I know that a risk-neutral person would be willing to pay `E(L2)-E(L1)=10`. Is a risk-averse person is willing to pay more than or less than her risk-neutral counterpart?

I've tried assuming utility functions ($U=x$ and $U=\sqrt{x}$) but the results become wildly incomparable. Is there any measure I can use to predict what a risk-averse person would be willing to pay?

Comment: I wonder if this is a better fit for the economics Stack.